# Visual Studio keymap for Eclipse is wrong

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-photon

I tried setting the provided Visual Studio keymap in Eclipse, but the shortcuts just do not seem to match. For example, to comment current line / selection, the Visual Studio hotkey was `CTRL+K,C` and it does not work in Eclipse.

EDIT: Also, in VS the default key to go to previous cursor position was `CTRL+-` .. in Eclipse this seems to be `ALT+-` even with the VS keymap enabled.

Is there anywhere I could find a proper keymap?

Comment: If you go to `Window->Preferences->General->Keys` you can choose your own keymap scheme, probably it's not set.

Comment: Sadly, it really seems to be set :(.. it's just that some of the combinations do not match. A good example is `CTRL+-` - in Eclipse it just decreases zoom level, while in VS it would take me to the previous cursor location.

Comment: Then in the selected key set, search for the binding which doesn't work(e.g. search for `Ctrl+` and see why it's not applied correctly ( maybe there are duplicate entries and the eclipse default is prefered).

Comment: @JohnDoe I apologize for not replying for so long. It does not seem to be the case.. for example, if I search for '-' in the shortcuts list, I only get one 'CTRL+-' assignment and that is to the 'Zoom out' action as opposed to Visual Studio where it would be 'Go to previous location'.

Comment: Then it seems like the keymap is not installed correctly or it doesn't have support(yet) for your desired actions. Maybe it's easier if you remap some of the existent keys in eclipse ( like you mentioned, the comment is bind to `Ctrl+/`, the previous cursor position is `Ctrl+left arrow`). Manually rebind them to your desired keys and then don't forget to export it and save it somewhere in case you reinstall eclipse.